# Understanding Circuitry from a Datasheet

Tags: circuit-design, driver, datasheet

I'm having a little difficulty understanding this section of a circuit from the datasheet for an [MC33035](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC33035-D.PDF) BLDC Motor Driver.

Some info:

- Pin 7 is enable, send pin high to enable motor
- Pin 8 is a 6.25v source
- Pin 14 is a fault pin, active low during a fault (at VCC (pin 17) not during a fault)

[image: Drawing]
I'm assuming during a fault "Latch on Fault" is closed, pushing the reset button would therefore send pin 7 high, re-enabling the motor.

However, following this logic then "Latch on Fault" would be open when the motor is running - but how is pin 7 sent high?

Or is it default high, closing the switch next to it pulls it down, or if "latch on fault" closes it pulls it down?

What is the 47uF cap for?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The 47uF capacitor de-bounces the Reset button.  So you get a long pulse, even for a short or bouncy operation of the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "Latch On Fault" is an optional switch via which you can set the behavior to display in case of a fault. It does *not* change with the fault state.

The logic is quite simple:

Pin 14 is low on fault, pin 7 is high for enabled. Now if you connect these pins, e.g. via a closed switch, once a fault is detected it also disables the motor by pulling enable low. If the switch is open, a fault will not disable the motor.

The reset button pulls the enable pin high again, overriding the fault signal of pin 14.

(For this logic to actually work, during fault pin 14 must stay low even when enable goes/is low.)

Answer (score 2):

"Or is it default high, closing the switch next to it pulls it down, or if "latch on fault" closes it pulls it down?"

Correct, pin 7 is pulled high by that little symbol shown to the right of it on the diagram - it's a 25uA current source internal to the chip. 25uA through a 4k7 resistor gives you 117.5mV across it, which is comfortably below the logic 0 threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Pin 7 has internal pull-up current source. Don't know why it is a source and not a resistor. Thus, you need to pull it down to disable motor control.

Haven't read the whole datasheet but 2.2k resistor and 47uF capacitor look like RC network filtering small "fault" spikes.

"Latch on fault" is either a manual switch or a latch that latches when the voltage across it crosses a threshold. If it is an automatic latch, latching will happen when sufficient "fault" spikes have been integrated over time.

Thus, 47uF capacitor acts as memory and retains the charge unless discharged via "reset" button. I think a current source has been used to discharge the capacitor in a known period of time for auto fault escape.